# JS global variable not changing outside of function scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in JS and I'm trying to implement a function inside a  '*Game Controller*' module that will handle the player's turn. The issue I'm running into is that a global property *'currentPlayer'* is not getting its value changed outside of the scope of the function that modifies it.

I've tried debugging using Dev tools and I can see the value changing but only inside the *'switchPlayerTurn*' function. Any suggestions here?

```
const GameController = (() => {
    const activePlayers = [];
    let currentPlayer = ''; 
    
   const _switchPlayerTurn = () => {
        if(currentPlayer === '') {
            currentPlayer = activePlayers[0];
        } else if(currentPlayer === activePlayers[0]){
            currentPlayer = activePlayers[1];
        } else if(currentPlayer === activePlayers[1]){
            currentPlayer = activePlayers[0];
        }
    }

    const init = () => {
        return createPlayers()
        .then(_switchPlayerTurn());
    }

    return {
        init,
        activePlayers,
        currentPlayer,
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning an object with `currentPlayer` only results in the object containing the value of `currentPlayer` at the moment of the return of the object. You need a function instead, so that you can retrieve the current value of the identifier inside on demand.

```
return {
    init,
    activePlayers,
    getCurrentPlayer: () => currentPlayer,
}
```

and then, wherever you're using it externally, use `.getCurrentPlayer()` instead of `.currentPlayer`

Comment: That was it! Thank you. That makes sense now. I have a follow-up question: the `activePlayers` array mentioned in the code above is also being used outside of the scope of the `GameController` object but I didn't have this issue. Is that because it's a different type of element?

Comment: It's probably because your `activePlayers` being used elsewhere doesn't get *reassigned*, but instead gets *mutated*, so anything in the code with a reference to the original array can see the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as elegant as @certainPerformance's answer, but for the sake of completeness... you could always define it outside your function scope so it is accessible globally all the time

```
let currentPlayer = ''; 
const GameController = (() => {
    const activePlayers = []; 
    // ...
```

Comment: That would work too but I'm trying to stay away from using too much global code.